# localhost vs hostname

Tags: debian, android

I am confused with `localhost(127.0.0.1)` and `hostname(127.0.1.1)` ,when I try for

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   JAZZ
```

and in case of `ifconfig` also I got about `localhost(lo:local loopback, 127.0.0.1`) ,

But when I tried this (`cat /etc/hosts`) on my android phone, by a bash emulator I got only 127.0.0.1 ,

```
android@user$cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1            localhost
```

Why there is no `hostname` in my android phone ??

Comment: Not every machine has a hostname set...

Comment: Thanx @Jan ,well tell me if my conception is wrong,,localhost is kind of server, and hostname is like a client . Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   JAZZ
```

In this example, the machine has 2 names: "localhost" and "JAZZ".

Not every machine has a hostname:

```
android@user$cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1            localhost
```

This is perfectly OK.